# Why do I keep get wrong result on this. Calculation wrong and cannot create empty input text alert

Tags: javascript, html

I am new on combination of HTML with JavaScript. This is my homework and my code have some problem need an expert to take a look. Here is the question.

If the hours worked is greater than 40 hours, compute by using 1.5 times regular rate for the extra hours. For example, if one works for 50 hours and the rate paid is $10.00/hour, the total pay should be $550.00.

My code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function calc() {
      var employ_name = document.getElementById('employ_name').value;
      var rate_pay = parseInt(document.getElementById('rate_pay').value);
      var hour_work = parseInt(document.getElementById('hour_work').value);
      if (hour_work <= 40) {
        alert("Paid Amount For " + employ_name + " is RM " + rate_pay * hour_work);
      } else {
        alert((40 * 1.5) + (c - 40) * c * 1.5);
      }
    }

    function calc() {
      if (document.getElementById("employ_name").value == "") {
        alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUE!");
        return false;
      } else if (document.getElementById("employ_no").value == "") {
        alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUE!");
        return false;
      } else if (document.getElementById("rate_pay").value == "" {
          alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUE!");
          return false;
        } else {
          alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUE!");
          return false;
        }
      }
  </script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="url" METHOD="POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Employee Name :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="employ_name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Employee No :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="employ_no"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rate of Pay :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rate_pay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hours Work :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="hour_work"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="Button" value="Submit" onclick="calc()"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you call `calc()` which of your two functions do you expect to execute and why?  What is the purpose of the second one that you don't expect to execute?

Comment: You have two functions named `calc()`.

Comment: how should I do, if i want to use one function name to show result and also the empty text field alert?

Comment: @AlvisLim: If you want two functions, give them different names so you can call them.  If you want one function, have one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. Your syntax is currently incorrect, you need to fix this by adding a closing bracket to your `if` statement:

   ```
   (document.getElementById("rate_pay").value == "") {...}
   ```
2. You have two functions with the same name. Instead, you need to give your second function a different name such as `checkInputs`, so that when you call the `calc` function, it will call the expected function.
3. Your second `calc` function (`checkInputs`) shouldn't be returning `false` if all `if-statments` fail. Instead, you should be returning `true` if they all `fail`, as this signifies they are all not empty.
4. To make your `calc` function check that all your inputs have a value within them, you can call your second `calc` function (now `checkInputs`) inside your first `calc` function. This way you can use an `if` statement to check if what `checkInputs` returns, and thus act accordingly.

See revised code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function calc() {
      if (checkInputs()) { // check if `checkInputs` returned true or false
        var employ_name = document.getElementById('employ_name').value;
        var rate_pay = parseInt(document.getElementById('rate_pay').value);
        var hour_work = parseInt(document.getElementById('hour_work').value);
        if (hour_work <= 40) {
          alert("Paid Amount For " + employ_name + " is RM " + rate_pay * hour_work);
        } else {
          // commented out as you have not show us what "c" is:
          // alert((40 * 1.5) + (c - 40) * c * 1.5);
        }
      } else { // if check inputs returned false then you can output error message
        alert("PLEASE ENTER THE VALUE!");
      }
    }

    function checkInputs() {
      if (document.getElementById("employ_name").value.trim() == "") {
        return false;
      } else if (document.getElementById("employ_no").value.trim() == "") {
        return false;
      } else if (document.getElementById("rate_pay").value.trim() == "") {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="url" method="POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Employee Name :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="employ_name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Employee No :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="employ_no"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rate of Pay :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rate_pay"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hours Work :</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="hour_work"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="Button" value="Submit" onclick="calc()"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** In your `checkInputs()` method I have also used `.trim()`. This will remove leading/trailing whitespaces on the input. This means if someone was to enter just spaces then `checkInputts` will return `false` isntead of `true`.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your correction. Now my code can run correctly with correct output. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @AlvisLim no worries :)))